# Swift - Trouble with TextField.clearsOnBeginEditing

Tags: swift, textbox

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()       
    self.enterNumberTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true  
}
```

Setting this bool true does not persist in later code, and i do not reset it in any of my code.  Setting the bool does not force the text box to clear when the user puts the cursor in it.  I check the value of the bool and it is true on the first pass through code, though the text box does not clear.  On subsequent passes through code the bool is reset to false.  not by my code.

I have also tried putting this line of code into the IBAction function where all the processing is done in this program. Same result.  Does not clear text box and is reset to false inside the if {} where all the work is done.

Can someone tell me why this is happening, and if there is a place where this bool should be set to true such that it persists throughout the program's execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I only had one text field and was never giving up focus. I added another text field to transfer focus to , now when I put focus back in the text field of interest, it does clear. Simple, must transfer focus for that method to work.

Answer (score 1):

From the Swift documentation:

> Even if this property is set to true, the text field delegate can override this behavior by returning false from its textFieldShouldClear: method.

Does your view adhere to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol? Do you implement the `textFieldShouldClear` method? This sounds like it could be the source of your problem.

EDIT:

What happens if you do something like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

That is, add the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol at the top, and then implement `textFieldShouldClear` so it always returns `true`. This may not be what you ultimately want, but it might solve the issue. Check out the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) for more info on protocols and delegation.

Comment: The program could not be more simple.  It is the standard ViewController.swift template created with a new project.  In it I add the text field and a button.  There is some processing after the button click.  Can you tell me where I would set the text field delegate to text field should clear.  Sorry, I'm inexperienced